# Aligning the peaks of two arrays

Tags: arrays, alignment

I have a tricky problem where I need to align the peaks of two arrays. Normally this wouldn't be "tricky", but in this case one is shorter than the other, and the shorter one can be segmented. Also, the solution cannot have overlapping segments. To illustrate, here are two vectors zero-aligned (this isn't a "real" case, per se, but it does demonstrate idea):
[image]

And here is (roughly) how I'd like to align them:

[image]

You can imagine, of course, that multiple solutions are possible - so it's really just a search optimization problem - i.e., find the spacing that produces an optimal fit.

I have a method for the segmentation that works acceptably well, and I also have a method for evaluating positions that prioritizes contour and difference between peaks (i.e., rather than overall difference), which is appropriate for my use case.

The first alignment algorithm I made is greedy, and though it solved this example problem, I realize that in some cases (possibly many!) it will fail to account for all segments, since *it will run out of room to shift into* before accounting for them all. So I can see that I have to try multiple positions, evaluate them, and pick the best one, but I'm trying to avoid having to test too many... One approach could apply the technique from this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787380, to layout the spaces between segments according to the partitions of an integer (i.e., the length difference of the original vectors). But, for my example problem, where that difference is 10, it means trying 2 ^ (10-1) = 512 possible arrangements, which I think is a bit heavy for my application.

Any thoughts (techniques, heuristics) would be greatly appreciated. I'm working in Swift, but that's not an important detail.

UPDATE: So, following the lead of @templatetypedef (sequence alignment, dynamic programming), I managed to get something pretty good. The alignment matrix is filled out according to:

[image]

where:

[image]

and both *s* and *q* have been normalized to [0,1]. Doing this by hand, I get something like this:

[image]

Pretty good! So, thanks to @templatetypedef for pointing me in the right direction.

It's worth noting, though, that this isn't exactly "compact", in that scaling the vectors, building the original matrix, extracting the path, and then re-formatting the final sequences all require a fair bit of iteration. On the other hand, my previous idea would also have the scaling, the segmentation, calculating the spacing permutations, aligning and evaluating, picking the optimal one, and formatting the result... The bonus of this method, of course, is that it's established, **and** it will also take care of the case where *s* and *q* are equal lengths (which is a pretty major bonus).

I can probably figure out the implementation, but if anybody has any tips, feel free to comment.

**UPDATE**

I did notice that the "gap penalty" of -1 is too high, given the calculation of the "match" score. I was able to get decent results in a number of cases with -0.5.

Comment: This sounds like it might be amenable to a dynamic programming algorithm along the lines of sequence alignment, except the cost has something to do with the slope. Have you investigated this?

Comment: I hadn't thought to look into sequence alignment (strangely), but I will, thanks. I had thought of adding a cost - specifically, on shifting - but I'll put some thought into your focus on slope...